# In italiano, quando si usa il presente e quando il gerundio?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, meaning, difference

In English it is very common to use the present-conjugation of 'to be' plus the ing-gerund form of the verb to describe an action in progress.

Ex: "I am talking to Tom".

Would both of the following be correct?

1) *Parlo con/a Tom*
2) *Sto parlando con/a Tom*

In contrast, if I wanted to say: "I talk to Tom", meaning that I am not currently talking to him, but on occasion we talk with each other, how would you differentiate that from *Parlo con Tom*?

This is just an example using one verb, but I would like to know when either case is more appropriate.

Comment: Both are correct, depending on the context. The “progressive form” with the gerund is not used as much as in English. For instance, *I'm living in Milan* would be *abito a Milano*; conversely, in order to express that I'm talking to Tom in this precise moment, *sto parlando con Tom* is correct.

Comment: Would "Parlo con Tom" just mean that I speak with Tom but not necessarily at this moment? Is it common to use this in Italian? Thanks.

Comment: *Parlo con Tom da mesi sull'uso del gerundio* would be perfectly grammatical (*I've been talking for some months with Tom about the usage of gerund*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reply as Italian mother tongue, I'm not an Italian teacher, hence my answer is practical, not technical.

I think *stare + gerundio* is more or less like the *-ing form* in English: the present simple is used for habits, while *stare + gerundio* is used for actions happening in this moment, for example:

> Di solito leggo libri di fantascienza *(habit)*, ma in questi giorni
> sto leggendo un libro giallo *(now)* **--> correct**

It is NOT correct to say:

> Di solito sto leggendo libri di fantascienza *(habit)*, ma in questi
> giorni leggo un libro giallo *(now)* **--> not correct**

Differently from English, we don't use *stare + gerundio* for the near future, for example it is NOT correct to say:

> Domani sto andando al mercato **--> not correct**

while it is correct:

> Domani andrò al mercato **--> correct**
>
> Domani vado al mercato **--> not completely grammatically correct but largely used in informal Italian**

Comment: Does avere + gerundio or essere + gerundio ever occur?

Comment: @pj2452 No, we don't use avere + gerundio or essere + gerundio: "ho facendo qualcosa" or "sono facendo qualcosa" are completly wrong